# What are the implications for India with EU Parliament getting 2020/2519(RSP) resolution discussed and passed?

Tags: india, european-parliament

I came across certain news articles from Indian media outlets mentioning a motion for passing a resolution [2020/2519(RSP)](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/B-9-2020-0082_EN.html) - on India’s Citizenship (Amendment) Act, 2019, that would be discussed in the European Parliament on Jan 29, 2020. I am looking to understand its effects on India.

MSN [reported](https://www.msn.com/en-in/news/newsindia/what-6-resolutions-in-european-parliament-on-caa-mean-for-india-eu-relations/ar-BBZmc8r?li=AAggbRN) that:

> Even if the resolutions are debated and passed, they are not binding on the European Commission.
>
> However, they can increase pressure on the Indian government at a time when it is grappling with strong criticism from Western powers, including key European Union (EU) members such as Germany, of its handling of the situation in Kashmir, the citizenship law and the NRC implementation in Assam.
>
> Experts believe the MEPs could also lobby politicians in their home countries to raise these issues.

An another [MSN piece mentioned](https://www.msn.com/en-in/news/newsindia/eu-distances-itself-from-its-lawmakers-anti-caa-move-not-our-official-position/ar-BBZo0Z8?li=AAggbRN) that:

> ...the opinions expressed by the European Parliament and its members “do not represent the official position of the European Union”.
>
> French diplomatic sources underlined that France, a founding member of the European Union, considers the new citizenship law an “internal political matter of India” and that European Parliament is an institution “independent of member states” and the European Commission.

If a resolution passed by the EU Parliament is not binding on the EU Commission and other EU institutions, what purpose does the discussion and passing of the resolution  would serve?

With non-binding nature of the resolution, I suppose that the EU member countries are at liberty to take or omit to take such measures which they deem fit to be mutually beneficial to their relation with India.

It is in this backdrop I'm asking what would that resolution actually achieve on the ground? And, how does that stand to affect India and to what degree?

Comment: The same purpose as other non-binding resolutions in parliaments [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-binding_resolution).

Comment: @Fizz given the nature of the report, a related although possibly separate question would be , can the EU Parliament pass a Binding Resolution at all?